# How to transform an 1D string array to a 2D array about the datetime

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

Consider I have an array containing the string of datetime:

```
       new_time[index]
Out[9]: 
array(['2012-09-01_00:00:00', '2012-09-01_01:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_02:00:00', '2012-09-01_03:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_04:00:00', '2012-09-01_05:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_06:00:00', '2012-09-01_07:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_08:00:00', '2012-09-01_09:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_10:00:00', '2012-09-01_11:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_12:00:00', '2012-09-01_13:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_14:00:00', '2012-09-01_15:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_16:00:00', '2012-09-01_17:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_18:00:00', '2012-09-01_19:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_20:00:00', '2012-09-01_21:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_22:00:00', '2012-09-01_23:00:00'], dtype='<U19')
```

Its shape is `(24,)`.The question is how can I assign it to a `(24,19)`array,and the rows of new array could look like following:

```
 ## one row of new array 
Out[10]: 
array([[b'2', b'0', b'1', b'2', b'-', b'0', b'9', b'-', b'0', b'1', b'_',
    b'0', b'0', b':', b'0', b'0', b':', b'0', b'0']], dtype='|S1')
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Probably with a view where dtype was uint8 or U1 or something

Comment: @MadPhysicist indeed `X.view('U1').reshape(X.size, -1).astype('S1')`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer why does `dtype='U1'` work, but `dtype='S1'` does not?

Comment: @MadPhysicist because the itemsizes don't match. If you view-cast from `U*` to `S1` every character gets distributed across 4 bytes. To get from `U` to `S` you have to use something like `astype`, i.e. actually create a new data buffer with the unicode characters expressed as single bytes.

Comment: @MadPhysicist If you are ok with a non-contiguous result you could actually do `X.view('S1').reshape(X.size, -1, 4)[..., 0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(['2012-09-01_00:00:00', '2012-09-01_01:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_02:00:00', '2012-09-01_03:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_04:00:00', '2012-09-01_05:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_06:00:00', '2012-09-01_07:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_08:00:00', '2012-09-01_09:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_10:00:00', '2012-09-01_11:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_12:00:00', '2012-09-01_13:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_14:00:00', '2012-09-01_15:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_16:00:00', '2012-09-01_17:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_18:00:00', '2012-09-01_19:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_20:00:00', '2012-09-01_21:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_22:00:00', '2012-09-01_23:00:00'], dtype='<U19')
```

You need to get to `S1` and reshape:

```
>>> a.view('U1').astype('S1').reshape(a.size, -1)
array([[b'2', b'0', b'1', b'2', b'-', b'0', b'9', b'-', b'0', b'1', b'_',
        b'0', b'0', b':', b'0', b'0', b':', b'0', b'0'],
       [b'2', b'0', b'1', b'2', b'-', b'0', b'9', b'-', b'0', b'1', b'_',
        b'0', b'1', b':', b'0', b'0', b':', b'0', b'0'],
       ...
       [b'2', b'0', b'1', b'2', b'-', b'0', b'9', b'-', b'0', b'1', b'_',
        b'2', b'3', b':', b'0', b'0', b':', b'0', b'0']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Viewing directly as `S1` does not work, because there are 4 bytes per charater:

```
>>> a.view('S1').shape
(1824,)
>>> a.view('U1').shape
(456,)
```

I you start with `S19`, you can view as `S1` immediately:

```
>>> b.dtype
dtype('S19')
>>> b.view('S1').reshape(b.size, -1)
array([[b'2', b'0', b'1', b'2', b'-', b'0', b'9', b'-', b'0', b'1', b'_',
        b'0', b'0', b':', b'0', b'0', b':', b'0', b'0'],
       ...
       [b'2', b'0', b'1', b'2', b'-', b'0', b'9', b'-', b'0', b'1', b'_',
        b'2', b'3', b':', b'0', b'0', b':', b'0', b'0']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Comment: Unicode is always good for a surprise. ;) Looks like there are 4 bytes per character.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with a non-contiguous view you can simply do:

```
X.view('S1').reshape(X.size, -1, 4)[..., 0]
```

or

```
X.view('S1').reshape(X.size, -1)[:, ::4]
```

Since this shares data with the original array it is very cheap, but you have to be aware that modifying this in-place will also change the original array. Of course, you can always make a copy.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your strings using list comprehension. Then you can get the 2D array using `np.asarray()` as

```
x = np.asarray(['2012-09-01_00:00:00', '2012-09-01_01:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_02:00:00', '2012-09-01_03:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_04:00:00', '2012-09-01_05:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_06:00:00', '2012-09-01_07:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_08:00:00', '2012-09-01_09:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_10:00:00', '2012-09-01_11:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_12:00:00', '2012-09-01_13:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_14:00:00', '2012-09-01_15:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_16:00:00', '2012-09-01_17:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_18:00:00', '2012-09-01_19:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_20:00:00', '2012-09-01_21:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_22:00:00', '2012-09-01_23:00:00'])

temp = []
for i in x:
    temp.append([j for j in i])
np.asarray(temp, dtype = 'S1')
```

---

Or in a very concise way you can do

```
temp = [[j for j in i] for i in x]   
temp = np.asarray(temp, dtype = 'S1')
```

Comment: Same time complexity as the other answer.

Comment: Not really. The other one is O(1) because it's making a view. You're copying the data, so O(n), and with a heavy load factor because you're using Python loops.

Comment: A view just creates another array structure with different metadata, but leaves the original underlying data untouched.

Comment: Well, nevwrmind, `astype` does make a copy. But there's a no-copy solution in the comments to the question.

Comment: Good call. Other solution is better. With an array size up to 1000 I still get the same execution time on my machine.

Comment: Would make sense for it to make a copy because I get the same execution time with even very large arrays.

Answer (score 0):

iterating through each value and then assigning it to a list, will solve this.

```
import numpy as np
array_24 = np.array(['2012-09-01_00:00:00', '2012-09-01_01:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_02:00:00', '2012-09-01_03:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_04:00:00', '2012-09-01_05:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_06:00:00', '2012-09-01_07:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_08:00:00', '2012-09-01_09:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_10:00:00', '2012-09-01_11:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_12:00:00', '2012-09-01_13:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_14:00:00', '2012-09-01_15:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_16:00:00', '2012-09-01_17:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_18:00:00', '2012-09-01_19:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_20:00:00', '2012-09-01_21:00:00',
    '2012-09-01_22:00:00', '2012-09-01_23:00:00'])
array_24.shape        #(24,)
array_24_19 = np.asarray([[j for j in i] for i in array_24])
array_24_19.shape     #(24, 19)
array_24_19[0]        #array(['2', '0', '1', '2', '-', '0', '9', '-','0','1', '_', '0', '0',':', '0', '0', ':', '0', '0'], dtype='|S1')
```

I hope this helps